# .libPaths() in R 3.2.2

Tags: r

Today I installed the latest version R 3.2.2 in my Windows 7 laptop. I already installed R 3.1.3 in this computer and don't uninstall it.

The `.libPaths()` is returned the personal library 3.1. See below

```
[1] "C:/Users/myusername/Documents/R/win-library/3.1"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library"
```

I normally expected the personal library path should be 3.2.

My question this is a new way R designed for, some problems in my laptop.

Thanks for any advice.